# Removing ads on apps that don't have ad-free version (e.g. Angry Bird)

Tags: applications, ads

My disabled child likes this game very much. But he can't handle the advertisement. It is just too much for him. I would like to get Angry Birds ad-free. I would pay for it, but there's no ad-free version on the Play Store.

The device is not rooted, and I'm not going to root it. So if possible, is there any solution for non-rooted device?

## .. several months later. Here is my solution

It seems impossible to disable ads on android games. Most of them are completely useless and some are glorifying war.

This is no problem for normal people.

For my disabled child this is information overload.

We bought an old standalone device. This kind of device where you need to buy games on cartridges. This solves my use case. AFAIK angry bird is not available for nintendo DSi, but other nice games.

Comment: "I would pay for it, but could not find a solution." What do you mean by that?

Comment: With "I would pay for it, but could not find a solution." I mean: I would pay for an ad-free version. But I could not find one. Do you understand this? Please ask again if not. I am not a native speaker. Maybe my wording is wrong.

Comment: Switch off your internet while playing Game!!

Comment: http://smile.amazon.com/Rovio-Entertainment-Ltd-Angry-Ad-Free/dp/B004SBQGHS?sa-no-redirect=1

Comment: Can someone please tell my why this question gets down-voted? Which rule does this question brake?

Comment: When I see apps that are capable to monetize only by ADS I uninstall them immediately. We are all so fed up of ADS. I found the best way of not showing video ads is to turn off the Wifi and set the mobile connection to 2G. This way the video ads which are big in size, never loads

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I don't like complicated work arounds like switching off internet connection or rooting the device, I choose this solution: uninstall it.

Comment: Please leave a comment why you think this is answer needs a down-vote. I am curious and always interested in improvements.

Comment: I guess because your question is _removing ads on apps..._, which this doesn't solve.

Comment: When I see apps that are capable to monetize only by ADS I uninstall them immediately. We are all so fed up of ADS. I found the best way of not showing video ads is to turn off the Wifi and set the mobile connection to 2G.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, install [Adaway](https://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/adaway/). It will remove ads basically everywhere.

Comment: The device is not rooted, and I don't want to root it.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch mobile data off or use airplane mode, ads won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use an app called LostNet Firewall Pro to block
angry birds from going online.
You can find it on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the app [Lucky Patcher](http://luckypatchers.com) to remove ads from apps.

A lot of its features are for root-only devices but it works on non-rooted devices as well.

With it installed, you can then patch an application to remove Google Ads, then reinstall the patched version (Uninstall and install) (if it also says "License verification found", you need to patch the APK modified for no ads to remove license verification).

(Except for using this app and writing a few custom patches for it, I am not affiliated with it in any way)

(Google Play Protect will block Lucky Patcher and call it malware. It can be safe to dismiss (More options > Install anyways (unsafe)) if you downloaded it from [the official site](http://luckypatchers.com/download).)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pihole. It will help block the ads on th DNS level. You can either get a raspberry Pi or install it on any computer. 
Link : https://pi-hole.net